# Send Gmail calendar invite from alternate email

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I've seen a lot of questions around this topic but most of them are about *receiving* invitations to your alternate email.

**I'm specifically looking for a way to send a calendar invite from my work email address which is not a Google account but is set up as a "Send mail as" option in my main Gmail account.**

I've tried all the suggestions I've seen out there including:

- adding my second email as an alternate email address. This still
  doesn't give me an option to create an event *as the new account*.
- changing the owner of the event to this second address, and then
  sending a subsequent invitation from it. The owner still comes
  through as my main Gmail account.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you need to make your work email address a Google Account. You should be able to create a Google account using your email address as the username. If I recall, you won't get Gmail but you'll have access to the other Google services.

Comment: Ok. Does that mean I can still use the "Send mail as" feature on my main Gmail account?

Comment: Should be. Note that there's a degree of speculation here, which is why it's a comment.

Comment: When trying to create a Google account with a non-gmail address I get the message "That looks like your email address. You can enter that below. Choose a new Google username (which will also be your new gmail.com address)." :(

Comment: Ah, well. It was only a guess.

Comment: @Seano Google must have changed their rules. I'm pretty sure it didn't used to be like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this now is to set up that second email address with a new GMail account. Don't forget to remove it as an alternate email address from your original account.

Comment: But that means having a custom domain, hence have the gsuite, right?

Comment: Yes , you ll need to have the gsuite.